# Do Cases FeedItem (Ex. TextPost, Activities) count against Salesforce storage limit?

Tags: case, casefeed, storage-limit

Chatter Feed is not counted against the Storage limit but Tasks are counted.
So I am confused about whether Cases FeedItem (Ex. TextPost, Activities) count against Salesforce storage limit or not.
If yes then under which object it is counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task/Event objects (collectively, Activities) count against storage, but Chatter Feed Items of all types do not. There are, however, separate [Chatter Allocations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_chatter_allocations.htm&type=5) and [Chatter Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_chatter_limits.htm&type=5) you should be aware of. In summation, you need not worry about FeedItem storage usage.